# Operator overloading+ to add multiple objects

Tags: c++, class, overloading, operator-keyword

I need to add multiple objects using operator overloading such as below:

```
ex1 operator+(const ex1 &c1, const ex1 &c2, more++){
    return ex1(c1 + c2 + more++);
}
```

This function adds two objects, however I want to add multiple objects. Is that possible?

```
int main(){
  // first for example I want to add 3 objects
  ex1 ob1, ob2, ob3;
  ob1 + ob2 + ob3;

  code..
  code..

  // and after that I want to add for example 10 or more objects  
  ex1 ob1, ob2, ob3,..., ob10;
  ob1 + ob2 + ob3 +....+ ob10;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter how many "values" (or objects) you want to add together, the operator function still only takes one (for member functions) or two (for non-member functions) arguments. The compiler will cascade the calls for you.

Comment: can you explain more your reply? you said that i can call the operator+ with any number of argument's?

Comment: No the compiler will generate the correct number of calls of your operator function. The function will always only be called with one or two arguments (depending on where it's declared), but the number of calls will increase as you add more values.

Comment: Just to experiment, why don't you write a simple `operator+` functions which does nothing but print something and return a default-constructed object, of course with only two arguments to make it work. That way you can easily see that the function gets called two times for e.g. `a + b + c`, three times for `a + b + c + d` etc.

Comment: Also, just think about it like that: Addition (the `+` operator) is a *binary* operator, meaning it has *two* operands: A left hand side and a right hand side. This is how addition works, in C++ as well as in real life. That the left hand side is the result of another addition doesn't really matter, the operator still has only two operands.

Comment: yes i check it thanks for your answer!

Comment: Finally,, if you have a user-defined object, one that you can modify, then most people recommend you make operator overload function member functions and not a non-member function.

Comment: Can you please check my update with a similar question?

Comment: You can't change the syntax of the language. The `+` operator is and will always be a binary operator, it will always take two operands.

Comment: can i have operation overloading but in the end of class object? not with + ..

Comment: check more clear my question in new thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34698185/operator-overloading-c

Answer (score 2):

You need only `overload +`  for two objects. It will then automagically work if you try to add three or more objects, because `a + b + c` is equivalent to `(a+b)+c`, or in terms of operator-function calls:

```
 operator+(operator+(a, b), c)
```

As long as you return an appropriate type from your + routine, you should be fine.

If you have an array of objects and want to sum all of them up, once again, you only need to overload operator + for two objects and then you can use the `std::accumulate` function from `<numeric>` header:

```
std::vector<ex1> objects = {/*...lots of objects*/};
ex1 sum = std::accumulate(objects.begin(), objects.end(), ex1());
```

**re update:**
By overloading operators in C++ you can change the return type and semantics of what an operator does, but you cannot change any of the following:

- the precedence of the operator (i.e. you cannot make `a+b*c` be equivalent to `(a+b)*c`
- the arity of the operator (i.e. you cannot overload a unary operator to take 2 operands and vice versa. You can't for example, make % work liks %a or a%
- you can't change if the (unary) operator is postfix or prefix, so you can't make the syntax `a-` or `a+` work

So the answer to your second question is no.

Comment: can you give me an example for multiple objects?

Comment: @therealp: a+b+c+d+e is equivalent to (((a+b)+c)+d)+e

Comment: Can you please check my update with a similar question??

Answer (score 2):

Just define

```
ex1 operator+(const ex1 &c1, const ex1 &c2){
    return ex1(c1.inner_value + c2.inner_value);
}
```

And then

```
a + b + c
```

Will be interpreted as

```
operator+(  operator+(a,b) , c )
```

So it should work

Comment: i want multiple class objects .. not 3 but multiple,3 was an example

Comment: While the operator function signature is correct and the calling order, the function will actually *not* work as the `operator+` function would be called recursively.

Comment: Right. I fixed the operator+ definition to not be recursive.

Comment: Can you please check my update with a similar question?

Answer (score 1):

If you want your overloaded operator to work for multiple objects, what you need is *chaining**, this could be ensured when you return your result by reference:

```
ex1& operator+(const ex1 &c1, const ex1 &c2){

    return ex1.var = c1.var + c2.var;
}
```

or if the operator is a class member:

```
ex1& operator+(const ex1 &rhs) {

    return ex1.var = this.var + rhs.var; 
}
```

once you have the above definition, you can add multiple objects as follows:

```
ex1 + ex2 + ex3
```

which will be equivalent to:

```
(ex1 + ex2) + ex3 => sum(ex1,ex2) + ex3 => sum(sum(ex1,ex2), ex3)
```

i.e. it is always reduced to binary operation between two operands.

**To answer your updated question**, here is a list of [all the operators that could be overloaded](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators), regardless of their arity (unary, binary) or affix (prefix, postfix). In the case of your updated question you are looking for postfix, unary operator overload.

*<sup>Multiple method calls, where each method returns an object, allowing the calls to be chained together in a single statement without requiring variables to store the intermediate results</sup>

Comment: Glad that I could help! :)

Comment: Can you please check my update with a similar question?

Comment: @therealp I would kindly advice you to accept the answer which satisfy the first part of the question and then ask a new question with the new topic. :)

Comment: thanks for help im new in this community but the system doesn't allowed me to create a new thread :(

Comment: Could you please clarify your down vote stranger, so that I can correct my answer ? :)

Comment: @simplicis veritatis You are returning a local variable by reference. Anyone that calls your `operator+` will be looking at undefined behavior.

Comment: @Mark B you are right, I was trying to brake it into separate lines to make it easier to understand. Thank you! Just edited. Should I be returning the first argument, as an overload of `stream`s or should I just return by value?

Answer (score 0):

With one exception, C++ only has unary operators and binary operators. The one exception is the ternary operator, exemplified by `x = condition ? 0 : 42;`. With regard to `operator+`, that is either a unary operator (e.g., `+42`) or a binary operator (`40+2`).

You can easily create a custom function that takes three `ex1` objects as input and somehow computes the sum of those three objects. However, you cannot call this function `operator+`. There's no place in C++ for an `operator+` that takes three arguments.

There are a number of ways around this restriction. The simplest is to create an overload of binary `operator+` that computes the sum of a pair of `ex1` objects, creating a new `ex1` object as output. The statement `ex1 d=a+b+c;` will result in two calls to `ex1 operator+(const ex1&, const ex1&)`. Both will create a temporary objects of type `ex1`. The temporary that represents the value of `a+b+c` is then passed to `ex1::operator=` to assign the value of that expression to `d`.

If you are doing this over and over and over, the creation of those temporary objects might well represent a performance bottleneck. If you are only doing this a few times, that performance bottleneck is a non-issue. The only time you need to worry is if this is an issue, and determining whether that's the case is an issue for you to resolve.

One way of overcoming this performance bottleneck is to create a function (or functions) that take more than two objects as input and creating a sum from those multiple objects. The downside is that you cannot name this function `operator+`, and hence you cannot use `d=a+b+c`. You'd instead have to use something like `ex1::add_three(ex1&d, const ex1&a, const ex1&b, const ex1&c)`.

Another approach is to use [expression templates](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Expression-template) as a means for implementing [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). Your `operator+(const ex1& a, constex1& b)` doesn't actually calculate `a+b`. It instead creates an object that *eventually* will calculate `a+b`. The expression `a+b+c` in turn creates another object that eventually will calculate that result. Finally, the expression `d=a+b+c` evaluates that expression and assigns it to `d`, and (if implemented correctly) does so without creating any temporaries.

This approach has also its downsides. Sometimes it is better to create a temporary. The [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) package does a very good job of determining when its better to create a temporary as opposed to using expression templates that defer calculation.